# what does the T separator in JavaScript Date

Tags: javascript, ios, date

I think I need clarification on something:

I have a string representing a date in a format like this:

```
'2013-12-24 12:30:00'
```

and if I pass it to Date(), then I get the following output

```
new Date('2013-12-24 12:30:00')
// --> Tue Dec 24 2013 12:30:00 GMT+0100
```

because iOS has problems with this, I read that I should use T as separator, however

```
new Date('2013-12-24T12:30:00')
// --> Tue Dec 24 2013 13:30:00 GMT+0100
```

the result adds one hour. I guess it has something to do with summer or winter, but what exactly does the T stand for, and why is the result different? I meanwhile solved my problem by passing separate parameters to the Date but I would still like to know where this extra hour is coming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
new Date('2013-12-24T12:30:00')
```

treats the time as UTC, so it's 12:30 in Greenwich and 13:30 in your timezone.

```
new Date('2013-12-24 12:30:00')
```

is a Chrome extension (or bug) that doesn't work in other browsers. It treats the time as local, so it's 12:30 in your timezone (GMT+1) and 11:30 in Greenwich.

Answer (score 0):

If you look closely... you will notice adding a **`T`** makes the time in 24-hour format.

```
new Date('2013-12-24T12:30:00')
// --> Tue Dec 24 2013 13:30:00 GMT+0100
```

Compared to

```
new Date('2013-12-24 12:30:00')
// --> Tue Dec 24 2013 12:30:00 GMT+0100
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess its stands for *Long time pattern*. Refer [this for more.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#LongTime)

Comment: That 'T' is the long time format specifier - its not necessarily the output.